# Rails 4 app + nginx1.4.4 + passenger4.0.37 on a headless Ubuntu12.x server running on a VM on my local machine

Tags: nginx, virtual-machines, ubuntu-12.04, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

At the moment, it gives me a disapointing blank page.
No 500, no 404, no errors on the nginx log file, just a snowstorm of interrogations. And its been hours of googling without success.
So if anyone can't help, it'll be greatly appreciated.

I want to be able to access my server running on a VM through my browser at *mysite.dev:8888*.

- So i've set my *hosts* file with *"127.0.0.1  mysite.dev"*.
- Set my VM to NAT network and forwarded the 8888 port on the host to 80 on the guest.

That works.

Now i know that nginx **is** handling requests. For a couple of hours, it was throwing the nginx custom either 404 or 500 error. So i tweaked here and there following the error_logs until, at last, the blank page.

## Here are my nginx config files

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user myuser myuser;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby;
    passenger_max_pool_size 6;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

---

#### And then:

`/etc/nginx/site-enabled/mysite`(which is an alias of a file with the same name in `/etc/nginx/site-available/mysite`

```
server {
    listen 80;  
    server_name mysite.dev;
    charset utf-8;
    root /home/myuser/public/clients/mysite.com/public/;

    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_spawn_method smart;
    rails_env production;


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /home/myuser/public/clients/mysite.com/public/404.html;


    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/myuser/public/clients/mysite.com/public;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

---

## So...

Is there supposed to be some kind of special **route** in my *routes.rb* file in order for nginx to serve my rails app? Because right now, it looks like there aint no app at all in the bunker.

This is `ls -la` on the top of mysite.com folder:

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 myuser myuser 4096 Mar  3 23:57 ./
drwxrwxr-x  5 myuser myuser 4096 Mar  4 00:01 ../
drwxrwxr-- 15 myuser myuser 4096 Mar  4 14:56 mysite.com/
drwxrwxr-x  7 myuser myuser 4096 Mar  4 17:54 .git/
```

And here is the actual mysite.com app:

```
drwxrwxr-- 15 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  4 14:56 ./
drwxrwxr-x  4 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  3 23:57 ../
drwxrwxr--  7 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  3 23:59 app/
-rwxrwxr--  1 myuser myuser 253413 Mar  3 23:59 backup.sql*
-rwxrwxr--  1 myuser myuser    488 Mar  3 23:59 Capfile*
drwxrwxr--  5 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  4 11:00 config/
drwxrwxr--  3 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  3 23:59 db/
drwxrwxr--  2 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  3 23:59 doc/
-rwxrwxr--  1 myuser myuser   1916 Mar  3 23:59 Gemfile*
-rwxrwxr--  1 myuser myuser   2483 Mar  3 23:59 Gemfile.lock*
drwxrwxr--  8 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  4 19:08 .git/
-rwxrwxr--  1 myuser myuser      0 Mar  4 09:28 .gitignore*
drwxrwxr--  3 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  3 23:59 lib/
drwxrwxr-x  2 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  4 14:56 log/
drwxrwxr-x  2 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  4 13:37 logs/
-rwxrwxr--  1 myuser myuser    306 Mar  3 23:59 notes.txt*
drwxrwxr-- 11 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  4 11:18 public/
-rwxrwxr--  1 myuser myuser    309 Mar  3 23:59 Rakefile*
-rwxrwxr--  1 myuser myuser     34 Mar  4 09:30 .rvmrc*
drwxrwxr--  3 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  3 23:59 script/
drwxrwxr--  6 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  3 23:59 test/
drwxrwxr--  5 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  4 14:56 tmp/
drwxrwxr--  4 myuser myuser   4096 Mar  3 23:59 vendor/
```

I'm seriously starting to think about uninstalling the whole nginx thing and reinstalling it via passenger, even though its pretty much what i have done in the first place...

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Where is your app?! You should have directories like `app`, `assets`, `public`, etc., `config.ru`, `Gemfile` and so on.

Comment: The app is _inside_ the mysite.com directory that you see there. I'll edit my question to show you the content...

Answer (score 0):

Passenger Root is pointing to an ini file, that seems wrong to me.  Unless I am missing something, that should be pointing to a directory where Passenger is installed, for instance: `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.37`

Comment: I've installed the phusion passenger package with nginx following their own guide found here:
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu
If i got it right, they say you dont need to install the passenger gem...
So the great part of my nginx.conf file was generated by the installation of phusion passenger package. That line is basically theirs:     passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;

Comment: Apparently As of Passenger 4 you can use Locations.ini for PassengerRoot.  What is the content of that file?  You are certain there is nothing in the error logs for nginx?

Comment: [locations]
natively_packaged=true
native_packaging_method=deb
bin_dir=/usr/bin
agents_dir=/usr/lib/passenger/agents
lib_dir=/usr/lib/passenger
helper_scripts_dir=/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts
resources_dir=/usr/share/passenger
include_dir=/usr/share/passenger/include
doc_dir=/usr/share/doc/passenger
ruby_libdir=/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
node_libdir=/usr/share/passenger/node
apache2_module_path=/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so
ruby_extension_source_dir=/usr/share/passenger/ruby_extension_source
nginx_module_source_dir=/usr/share/passenger/ngx_http_passenger_module

Comment: Nothing at all in the nginx error_logs file. Its as if everything was rolling...

Comment: You just see a white page?  I am guessing (again this is only a guess) that your Application may be to blame because if there is no error by nginx or passenger, perhaps the your application is not generating content properly.  Does your app have error handling of any sort?

Comment: -The live app runs with nginx and passenger.
-My actual dev env runs the rails app fine with webrick on localhost:3000
-I'd rather switch my dev env over to my Ubuntu VM server running the same environment as the live app. But it seems like nothing but a blank page is showing up. Could it have anything to do with the database?